# Migrating from maven to bazel

Tags: java, spring, maven, unit-testing, bazel

Hi I am trying to migrate my project from maven to bazel.
One of the challenge I am facing is migrating test configuration.

While initializing the test, code writes some config properties to properties file.
In one of the test configuration, it tries to create this properties file in "/target" location which maven creates by default.

But after migrating those tests to run with bazel, it doesnt find the folder named target and hence fail the tests.

Changing each and every test with the different folder will be huge task.
Is there a way in bazel to create maven like folder structure ?

Comment: Just curious: Why do you want to migrate from Maven to Bazel?

Comment: Bazel builds are faster as compared to maven and bazel supportsdo increamental builds and other many useful features which reduces build time significantly and hence help developers increase the productivity.

Comment: My philosophy is to stick to software with large market share (for Java builds: Maven  or Gradle) because you get a stable solution and find much information on the internet.

Comment: You ought to explore new things when existing have some problems.

Comment: Maven is not without problems, but we managed to solve most of them through the various sources on the internet, especially Stackoverflow. For Bazel, this is much harder. You see that nobody answers your question here. If you want incremental builds, I would look into Gradle.

Comment: @JFMeier StackOverflow does not recommend using the comment section for secondary discussions (e.g. merits of build systems on a question about one specific system). Please see [the docs about commenting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

Bazel runs tests in a directory denoted by the [environment variable `$TEST_SRCDIR`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/test-encyclopedia.html#initial-conditions) and has access to a temp directory `$TEST_TMPDIR` during the test. I believe the only approach here would be the augment every test to either not write to `target/`, or write to `$TEST_TMPDIR` instead of `target/`.

Also, unlike Maven, Bazel does not allow your tests to write to your sources' directory. This is to ensure reproducibility and hermeticity, and is the reason why Bazel runs tests in a separate clean room environment created independently for each test.